# EPP Protocol create multiple domains in one command

Tags: protocol

I've seen `<domain:check>` command can check multiple domains in one command. Is it possible to do the same for the `<domain:create>`?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
     <command>
       <create>
         <domain:create
          xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">
           <domain:name>example.com</domain:name>
           <domain:period unit="y">2</domain:period>
           <domain:ns>
             <domain:hostObj>ns1.example.com</domain:hostObj>
             <domain:hostObj>ns1.example.net</domain:hostObj>
           </domain:ns>
           <domain:registrant>jd1234</domain:registrant>
           <domain:contact type="admin">sh8013</domain:contact>
           <domain:contact type="tech">sh8013</domain:contact>
           <domain:authInfo>
             <domain:pw>2fooBAR</domain:pw>
           </domain:authInfo>
         </domain:create>
       </create>
       <clTRID>ABC-12345</clTRID>
     </command>
   </epp>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [EPP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5731#section-3.2.1) indicates you must have a `domain:create` element inside the `create` element. It does not specify if you can have more, but it never mentions the possibility of having more than one domain created simultaneously, so I guess this is not possible.